# Can I use facebook Android API to monitor the android apps my friends are playing?

Tags: android, facebook, api

Is it possible to use the android facebook API to see what apps (games) your friends are playing and is there a way to use that data for your own application?

Answer (score 0):

To 'monitor' your friends, they need to install your app(on mobile) or/and give you the permission to do so. Also as far as my knowledge goes, there is no such api which tells which all apps a user is using... Not sure though.